# Going through array element OnClickListener android studio

Tags: java, android, loops, button, click

I am struggling to go through each element of an Array at each button click, I can make a counter increase or decrease at each button click but I want to use `for` loop or `while` loop to do count or to go through each element of array.

Here is my code:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
              d = String.valueOf(amp[j]);

              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, d, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }//outer
      }
});
```

I also declared a global array variable  `int[] amp = {4,8,7};`

The problem is the loop prints each element at button click but what I want is on first click print first element of array, and if I click button again then print second element of array and so on.

Comment: you can create variable like int numberOfClicks and according to its value, print the array

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
int counter = 0;

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @ Override public void onClick(View v) {
            d = String.valueOf(amp[counter]);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, d, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            counter++;
            if(counter>amp.length)
                counter=0;
    }
});
```

Comment: many thanks Mohammed Bakr Sikal but i know that way but i need to use index number of forloop or while loop for instance i want my array list printed according to my index e.g i have array  int amp[]={5,3,7}  i want to print each element at one time but using index value of loop e.g for(int i=0i<amp.lemgth;i++){code here to print amp[index of i]}because i nedd to know which index is created i need this information to know element index of then i can clear that index instead of hardcoding position

Comment: Edit your post with the intended input and outputs.

Comment: ok i want to create marker on each click to google map, then i can tackle individual marker to remove them if i use index of loop, but how can i remove individual marker from google map without hardcoding, so i like to get result of element of array but using while or do or for loop so i need to use index of loop

Comment: The counter I suggested in my post is acting like an manual index of a loop. You can use map.clear() then add your new marker. Or, an other alternative would be to insert all your markers at the beginning, hide them (marker.setVisible(false);), then onClick, you are just making the marker with that index visible.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need a for loop or while loop to do this. It can be accomplished simply by using an index variable and an if/else statement. Here, `index` is a member variable initialized to 0.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(index < amp.length){ 

                d = String.valueOf(amp[j]);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, d, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Increment index until we hit the last element
                index++;

            }else {
                // You can reset the index here so it starts at 0 once again
                index = 0;
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: thanks 11m0  ok i will tell you why i need loop.. because i want to create a list of LAtLing on each click a marker will b add to google map then on click on each markeri want to be able to removed, i think it is not possible to remove individual markers unless you have index of loop  e.g if i say on index of element add marker then io be able to remove marker at index of loopp aswel

Comment: what i want to do i want to be able to add marker at position loop then i can ude marker.remove at position loop aswell without knowing what index it is done automaticaly

Comment: will make new thread to ask for google map thanks for youar answera